# Make objc dot grammar compile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, clang

As we know, `obj.foo` will be compiled to `[obj foo]` as @property getter

My `obj` is a proxy object that store properties at runtime.
But `-foo` selector won't define at compile time

```
id obj = ...; // obj can perform -foo at runtime, but not at compile time  
id obj1 = [obj foo]; // may compile  
id obj2 = obj.foo;  // compile error
```

Could I use some `#pragma` trick to stop compile-time checking?
Or somehow makes compiler happy?

Comment: what's the error the compiler is giving you?

Comment: `property not found on object of type id`

Comment: What is the name of the class that declares property `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

If `obj` is a proxy to an object of type `Foo` (which has a `foo` property) just do what's natural and use `Foo *` as its type.

The compiler will allow dot syntax only if the static type is known to respond to this selector. `id` will not work.

Comment: I wanna translate JSON into objc `Model objects`, but I try not to write those Model classes(or protocols), instead, I build a `proxy` object(a mutable dictionary could do it's job), forward `-foo` to `objectForKey`. Everything prepared, only I could compile those code.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `obj` as type `id` you are telling the compiler that `obj` could be an instance of any class, so the compiler does not know if it has any specific properties or methods. If you must maintain that `obj` can be more than one class, but only classes that have a `foo` property, try using a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

```
id<ObjectWithFoo> obj = /* ... */
obj.foo // no error
```